# env PATH not working when I openssh to Windows server

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cygwin, sshd

I've set up git on a windows machine with a working PATH environment variable.  From both the command line and Cygwin terminal I can use

```
git status
```

I've also installed ssh as a service using Cygwin and sshd using the guide here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23562_01/doc.1035/e14501/install.htm.  I can successfully ssh to the machine using Putty, but when I try to run git commands, it seems the PATH I've set up doesn't work.  Instead I get:

```
-bash: git: command not found
```

Is there any way to get this working **with a PATH variable**?  This is going to be used by Jenkins so I have limited control over how the git commands are called.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Cygwin or the ssh client maintains its own PATH so I just needed to add my git.exe path in my ssh session in this way:

```
export "PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd"
```